# Changing baking tins

Tags: conversion

I have a recipe that uses a 20cm round tin (7.5cm deep), I want to make the cake in three 20cm shallow tins, do I need to alter the time and temp?

Hope this makes sense.

Trish

Comment: Are you saying the recipe calls for a single tin?

Answer (score 1):

The thinner cakes will cook faster. I can't get more specific without knowing what type of cake you are baking.